# allocate 2D array of structs

Tags: c, struct, malloc

im trying to allocaet a2D array of struct to make a board for class assignment
in c
This is what I have written so far but I keep getting run time error.

```
int** makeboard(int** board,int size)
{
    
    printf("Enter board size numbers: \n");
    board = (int*)malloc(size * sizeof(int*));
    if (!board) {
        printf("error");
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        board[i]= (int*)malloc(size * sizeof(int));
    }
    return board;
}
```

```
I would appreciate any help / points for improvement and thank you in  for your time
```

Hear different perspectives and approaches on the question

Comment: This looks fine.  The problem is probably elsewhere in your code.  Try running your code through valgrind.  If you're mismanaging memory it will tel you where.

Comment: `board = (int*)malloc(...)` will emit a warning. Tip:  don't cast the result of malloc

Comment: What is the purpose of `board` parameter? Its value is never used